# Have separate functions for single click and a long press key

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I have a button, I want to call different functions based on whether the user has clicked the button once or long pressed it.

The single click works fine, however if I long press the button, the long press function is executed, followed by the single click function.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
var timeout, clicker = $('#clicker');
var count = 0;

clicker.mousedown(function(){
timeout = setInterval(function(){
    clicker.text(count++);
}, 500);

return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
clearInterval(timeout);
return false;
});


clicker.click(function(){
$(this).css('background', 'red');
return false;
});
```

​

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8FmRd/181/

On the first long press the color of the div shouldn't change to red.

Comment: The fiddle you linked doesn't match the code in your question - which one should we be looking at?

Comment: the code was the latest one, never mind, got the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8FmRd/189/

```
var timeout, clicker = $('#clicker');
var count = 0;

clicker.mousedown(function(){
    count = 0;
    timeout = setInterval(function(){
        clicker.text(count++);
    }, 500);

    return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(timeout);
    return false;
});

clicker.click(function(){
    clearInterval(timeout);
    if (count < 1) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: What happens is that the timeout variable is getting overwritten when a second mousedown happens without a mouseup. This leaves the first interval stranded to loop forever. You can fix this by tracking whether the interval is already going and disabling the mousedown if it is. This works regardless of the mouse button used.

The original example and the solution provided by Gustonez both seem to have a slight bug in that if you  right click in the middle of a left click press and then release both, the timer keeps running. I believe this is because the right click also triggers a mousedown event, but the mouseup is getting drowned by the context menu that appears. Either way, you can solve this by disabling the mousedown for right clicks. (A right click is indicated by an element.which value of 3)

```
var timeout, clicker = $('#clicker');
var count = 0;
var active = false;

clicker.mousedown(function(e){
    if (active) {
        return false;
    }

    timeout = setInterval(function(){
        clicker.text(count++);
        $(this).css('background', 'orange')
    }, 500);

    active = true;

    return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(timeout);
    active = false;
    return false;
});


clicker.click(function(){
    clearInterval(timeout);
    active = false;
    return false;
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8FmRd/634/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `clicker.click` and in your mouseup event check the count, for instance:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
   clearInterval(timeout);
   if(count < 2) {
      $(this).css('background', 'red');
   }
   return false;
});
```

Click will happen not depending on how long you hold a button. Also, you may take start click time in mousedown and check the difference in mouseup event and change the background only if difference is less than X milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

Just update your clicker function to following

```
clicker.click(function() {
    if(clicker.text() < 1) {       
       $(this).css('background', 'red');
    }
   return false;
});​
```

Here is jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8FmRd/187/

Answer (score 1):

Like FAngel pointed out, you could also use a start-end difference, wrote the code while other answers already were posted :P:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FmRd/188/)

```
var timeout,
    timerStart,
    timerEnd,
    count = 0,
    interval = 500;

$(document).on({
    mousedown: function() {
        timerStart = new Date().getTime();

        var $clicker = $(this);
        timeout = setInterval(function(){
            $clicker.text(count++);
        }, interval);
        return false;
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        timerEnd = new Date().getTime();
        clearInterval(timeout);

        if(timerEnd - timerStart < interval) {
            $(this).css('background', 'red');
        }
        return false;
    }
}, '#clicker');
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach some data to the element on mousedown event and check it on click event.
Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8FmRd/184/).